# How to log operations in Couchbase?

Tags: logging, couchbase

I want to log every operation in Couchbase, for e.g:

- Create data
- Delete data
- Update data
- Who did it and when if it's possible

Does Couchbase provide any function like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe Couchbase offers that sort of service at the moment. You can have a look at the logs page ( [couchbase logs](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Misc/Trbl-logs.html) ) but as I said I dont think it's what you need.

Perhaps a better way to go here would be write your own frontend for couchbase which logs what you want.

Comment: You are correct. Couchbase has no built-in way to audit CRUD operations as of this moment. The application will need to do this level of auditing.

Comment: Thanks, understood, it's OK to let the frontend logs, but I am confused how to manage the logs?   The data will grow fast, no matter save the data in file or database. Should I use any log management tool or something?

Comment: There are various log managing tools depending on your environment and needs. This really deserves a lot more room than a comment, but you could use logrotatae (a linux utility) to manage log size. A common solution is to use a combination of tools - like the ELK stack - to ship your logs into a db where they can be easily searched via a visualizer. google it. 

also, if you liked this answer, please accept it. thx!

Comment: Thank you for that. I am new here, just know I can accept it right now. :)